Filebeat Multiline pattern not working if dynamic space is in the pattern
Below is my incoming log from JVM GC output
[2024-10-16T00:53:05.165+0000][6.308s][gc,heap] GC(0)  Metaspace       used 12167K, committed 12480K, reserved 1114112K
[2024-10-16T00:53:05.165+0000][6.308s][gc,heap] GC(0)   class space    used 1260K, committed 1408K, reserved 1048576K
[2024-10-16T00:53:05.165+0000][6.308s][gc     ] GC(0) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 51M->10M(1032M) 12.441ms
[2024-10-16T00:53:05.165+0000][6.308s][gc,heap] GC(1)  Metaspace       used 12167K, committed 12480K, reserved 1114112K
[2024-10-16T00:53:05.165+0000][6.308s][gc,heap] GC(1)   class space    used 1260K, committed 1408K, reserved 1048576K
[2024-10-16T00:53:05.165+0000][6.308s][gc     ] GC(1) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 51M->10M(1032M) 12.441ms
[2024-10-16T00:53:05.165+0000][6.308s][gc,heap] GC(2)  Metaspace       used 12167K, committed 12480K, reserved 1114112K
[2024-10-16T00:53:05.165+0000][6.308s][gc,heap] GC(2)   class space    used 1260K, committed 1408K, reserved 1048576K
[2024-10-16T00:53:05.165+0000][6.308s][gc     ] GC(2) Pause Full (System.gc()) 3531M->2934M(7696M) 3796.534ms

From above i need to split with multiline pattern as all GC(0) to 1 message and GC(1) to another etc..Below is the pattern i tried which i am unable to get trying to split with "[gc     ]" field in between a line at the end of each GC output:
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - "/opt/micro_service/TA/MOUNT/gc_logs/s1gc3.log"
  multiline.pattern: '^\[gc[[:space:]]\](.)*?'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: before

Pls let me know the issue

You try to split with [gc ] when you actually have [gc,heap] or [gc     ]. try starting with this regex instead \[gc[^\[]*\] ?(.+)

Did you try \[gc[^\]\[]*\] GC\([0-9]+\) and multiline.negate: false

Please try this one, instead of "log" input , use "filestream" input.
filebeat.inputs:
- type: filestream
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - "/opt/micro_service/TA/MOUNT/gc_logs/s1gc3.log"
  parsers:
  - multiline:
      type: pattern
      pattern: '^\[gc[[:space:]]\](.)*?'
      negate: true
      match: after

Note: In pattern you can mention like below also
pattern: ' Metaspace       used '

